# How to create a group of unique users in C# console application with name, username and password where username is unique for all users?

Tags: c#, dictionary, authentication, data-structures, console-application

I have a programming problem where I have to create a C# console application for login data. The data is username, password and the user's name. The username is unique for all users. I cannot use a text file or a database to store the data. The data can be stored in a data structure like an arraylist or dictionary or any other appropriate data structure. I tried to use a dictionary in a separate class where the key is supposed to be username and I have created a list comprising the corresponding password and the name, and inserted it in the dictionary. But I cannot achieve the required result as predicted as I don't know how to get the data to be stored exactly and retrieve it accordingly. Do I create a new object in a different class and store the data in there as a dictionary(or other data structure) or create a static method which contains a dictionary(or other data structure) and store the data there. I tried using an arraylist too but in vain.

->The data needs to persist as long as the application is running.

->The data needs to be available to make the user login after creating the username and password.

->The user must have a unique username authenticated by the key in data structure.

Any help is appreciated as I'm stuck with this for hours now. Just guide me where I am going wrong, whether in choosing the data structure or the whole logic altogether. Any suggestion is welcome.
I have created the program as follows:

```
using System;
using Users;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

namespace Assignment_3
{
    class Login
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            int input;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Choose one of the following:");
                Console.WriteLine("1: Create a new Username and Password");
                Console.WriteLine("2: Login");
                Console.WriteLine("3: Exit");
                Console.WriteLine();

                input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (input)
                {
                    case 1:
                        //Username and pass logic
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter a new Username");
                        string user = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter a new Password");
                        string pass = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter your full name");
                        string name = Console.ReadLine();

                        AllUsers.userList(user, pass, name);
                        ListOfAllUsers.Listy(user, pass, name);
                        /*RealUsers newUser = new RealUsers();
                        newUser.username = user;
                        newUser.password = pass;
                        newUser.name = name;
                        */
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //After successful login new code here                                                       
                }
            } while (input != 3);
        }
    }
}

namespace Users
{
    class ListOfAllUsers
    {
        public ListOfAllUsers()
        {
            
        }
        public static void Listy(string username,string password,string name)
        {
            ArrayList allInOne = new ArrayList();
            List<string> threes = new List<string>();
            threes.Add(password);
            threes.Add(name);
            allInOne.Add(username);
            allInOne.Add(threes);
            foreach (var item in allInOne)
                Console.Write(item + ", ");
            


        }
    }

    class RealUsers
    {
        public string name;
        public string username;
        public string password;
        public Dictionary<String, List<String>> user()
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<String>> Usernames = new Dictionary<string, List<String>>();

            List<string> passAndName = new List<string>();
            passAndName.Add(password);
            passAndName.Add(name);

            Usernames.Add(username, passAndName);
            return Usernames;
        }
    }
    class AllUsers
    {
        public static void userList(string username, string password, string name)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<String>> Usernames = new Dictionary<string, List<String>>();

            List<string> passAndName = new List<string>();
            passAndName.Add(password);
            passAndName.Add(name);

            Usernames.Add(username, passAndName);
            
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp in Usernames)
            {
                foreach (string value in kvp.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, value);
                }
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic to ensure unique entries in the Dictionary is much simpler than what you've posted.  I'm not sure why you even have a separate namespace called Users with a bunch of classes that I don't see a need for.  You can achieve what you want with just this code.

```
class Login
{
    private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> AllUsers = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int input;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Choose one of the following:");
            Console.WriteLine("1: Create a new Username and Password");
            Console.WriteLine("2: Login");
            Console.WriteLine("3: Exit");
            Console.WriteLine();

            input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (input)
            {
                case 1:

                    //Username and pass logic

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a new Username");
                    string user = Console.ReadLine();

                    while (AllUsers.ContainsKey(user))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Username already exists. Enter a different Username");
                        user = Console.ReadLine();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a new Password");
                    string pass = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter your full name");
                    string name = Console.ReadLine();

                    AllUsers.Add(user, new List<string>() { pass, name });
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //After successful login new code here  
                    break;
            }
        } while (input != 3);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: More refined answer, based on comments**

Below is the same code, but it uses a class called "User" to be cleaner.

```
namespace Assignment_3
{
    class Login
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, User> AllUsers = new Dictionary<string,User>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int input;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Choose one of the following:");
                Console.WriteLine("1: Create a new Username and Password");
                Console.WriteLine("2: Login");
                Console.WriteLine("3: Exit");
                Console.WriteLine();

                input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                string user, pass, name;
                switch (input)
                {
                    case 1:

                        //Username and pass logic

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter a new Username");
                        user = Console.ReadLine();

                        while (AllUsers.ContainsKey(user))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Username already exists. Enter a different Username");
                            user = Console.ReadLine();
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter a new Password");
                        pass = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter your full name");
                        name = Console.ReadLine();

                        AllUsers.Add(user, new User(user, pass, name));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter your Username");
                        user = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter your Password");
                        pass = Console.ReadLine();

                        if (AllUsers.ContainsKey(user) && AllUsers[user].Password == pass)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Congratulations, {AllUsers[user].Name}, you are now logged in!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Login failed!");
                        }
                        break;
                }
            } while (input != 3);
        }
    }
}

namespace Users
{
    class User
    {
        public string Username { get; private set; }
        public string Password { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public User(string username, string password, string name)
        {
            Username = username;
            Password = password;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response sir. I was trying to create a separate class for user login data making the code cleaner. I am trying to create a dictionary object in "users" class. I will need that data to make the user login using those credentials(case 2 as above where I will add the logic later). It must persist as long as the program is running. Can you help out in this scenario please.

Comment: I think that structurally, creating a "Users" class that holds a Dictionary is pointless.  The Dictionary that I used is already persistent throughout the lifetime of the program without putting it in a class.  It's more beneficial and cleaner if you create a "User" class to represent a single user, then rely on a Dictionary<> or List<> to represent the "users".  Let me refine my answer above using a User class to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

With the caveat that there are **glaring** security concerns - but I get the impression this is more of an exercise than a project for publication - this could be done fairly simply by creating an object in which to store your data, and instantiating a list of that object in Main.

```
public class User{
     string UserName {get; set;}
     string Password {get; set;}
     string Name {get; set;}
}
```

And then in Main:

```
List<User> UserList = new List<User>();

public void AddUser(){
    User NewUser = new User();
    //gather user data as you did in your example
    UserList.Add(NewUser);
}
```

You can then iterate over that list as often as necessary when selecting a User object in your code.